# jqGrid - how to find iRow (index of the row) from rowId (table pri key)

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have rows from a table in jqGrid. I manipulate the behaviour of `cellEdit` and now use it for editing. After I init the grid, I will use;

```
$('#grid').editCell(iRow,1,false);
```

to just select the cell.

but I have only `rowId` not `iRow`. How can I get `iRow` from `rowId`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The index of the row (iRow) you can get using [rowIndex](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_tablerow_rowindex.asp) property of the DOM object which represent ther row `<tr>`. So you need just get the DOM of the row. If the `rowId` don't contain any [meta-characters](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) you can do just the following

```
var iRow = $('#' + rowId)[0].rowIndex;
```

For the more common case you can use [jqID](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.3.1/js/grid.base.js#L131-133) function which escapes the meta-characters if needed:

```
var iRow = $('#' + $.jgrid.jqID(rowId))[0].rowIndex;
```

Comment: Thank you very much... It worked. In addition if we have more than 1 grid in page we can use 
var iRow = $('#gridId #' + rowId)[0].rowIndex;

Comment: @OnurErenElibol: You are welcome! The id of any element is unique on the page so you can use `$('#' + rowId)[0].rowIndex` independent from the number of grids. The `$('#gridId #' + rowId)[0].rowIndex` will also work and get the same results, but it will work *slowly*. It's important that **all element** on the page has unique id. So you can't use the same rowid for different grids on the page. If you do have conflicts you can use `idPrefix` option of the grid.

Comment: When I have 2 grids binded with 2 different tables, I may be have 2 same id's for different grids. In html it's not acceptable (thanks to you for this good point). I think I will use **idPrefix**.